# Converting decimal to binary using loop and displaying it - Assembly Language EMU 8086

Tags: assembly, binary, emulation, x86-16

In the code below i am trying to convert the value in count to binary and then displaying it. The code does not seem to work and only displays 1 when it should be displaying for example 1000 for 8 but instead it displays one for each value. Any advice on what i should change or do to improve my code?

I also tried to display a counter but gave up after failing misreably and am using `N1`, `N2` etc. to display numbers instead of using a loop which would make my code shorter by a mile and improve it. Please advise me on that as well :)

Lets say i want to start the counter from 0 or 1, the value I want to display, should it be in ascii code or hexa decimal? Like for example, i want to display number 5 and then 6. (example will be shown in second code segment). Would code 2 work? what should be changed to make it work? Should a ascii value be put into `CX`? Should i use a memory variable instead?

CODE 2 NOTE: 2 Dots represent code omitted, please ask if you do not understand the code properly. Please do not mind these questions, I'm still an amateur at coding and have difficulty doing the simplest of things. Thanks for reading :)
Here is the code for the whole program for people who need it: [Full Code Here](https://www.mediafire.com/?z67acsnskx656gu)

CODE 1:

```
OUT1 MACRO COUNT ;new macro added, edit date 7th july
MOV CL,COUNT
MOV AL,CL            
MOV DX,0378H
OUT DX,AL 
ENDM

CURSOR  MACRO Col, Row
push ax
MOV AH,02
MOV BH,00
MOV DL,Col
MOV DH,Row
INT 10H
pop ax
ENDM

DISP   MACRO MES
push ax
MOV AH,09
MOV DX,OFFSET MES
INT 21H
pop ax
ENDM

.DATA
.
.
N0              DB      '0','$'
N1              DB      '1','$'  
N2              DB      '2','$'
N3              DB      '3','$'
N4              DB      '4','$'
N5              DB      '5','$'
N6              DB      '6','$'
N7              DB      '7','$'
N8              DB      '8','$'
N9              DB      '9','$'
COUNT           DB      0
TWO             DB      2
STR1            DB      4 DUP('$') ; ADDED NEW
COL1            DB      36 ; ADDED NEW
.
.
.code
.
MOV COUNT,5
.
.
    BINARY: LEA SI,STR1
        PUSH CX
        MOV CL,4
BINL1:  MOV AL,COUNT
        CBW
        DIV TWO
        MOV BYTE PTR[SI],AH
        INC SI
        DEC CL
        JNZ BINL1
        POP CX
        JMP PRINTBINARY

PRINTBINARY:    MOV AH, BYTE PTR[SI]
                PUSH CX
                PUSH AX     
                MOV CL,4
PBIN1:          CURSOR COL1,22 ; 36,22 then 35,22 to 33,22
                CMP AH,0
                JE ZERO
                JNE ONE
ZERO:           DISP N0
                JMP X
ONE:            DISP N1
x:              DEC SI
                DEC CL
                JNZ PBIN1
                POP AX
                POP CX
                JMP L0
```

CODE 2:

```
mov cx,5
disp cx
inc cx
disp cx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested the linked code. The problem is the algorithm to convert from number ("count") to binary ("str1"). I made three changes, **corruptdna** must replace next codes in your code and run it:

**1.** Added one more byte to variable "str1" to store '$' at the end and display it with int 21h, ah=9 :

```
STR1            DB      5 DUP('$')
```

**2.** Changed the algorithm to convert from number ("count") to binary ("str1"). Dividing is not the proper way, I right-shifted the bits, converting each extracted bit in '0' or '1' and storing these chars in "str1" :

```
BINARY: MOV SI,OFFSET STR1+3     ;POSITION OF THE LEAST SIGNIFICANT BIT (EXTREME RIGHT).
        PUSH CX
        MOV CL,4
        MOV AL,COUNT
BINL1:  
        SHR AL, 1                ;PUSH BITS TO THE RIGHT. BIT 0 IN CARRY FLAG.
        JC  BIT_1                ;IF ( CARRY FLAG == 1 ) JUMP TO BIT_1.
        MOV [ BYTE PTR SI ], '0' ;IF NO JUMP, BIT IS ZERO.
        JMP NEXT_BIT             ;SKIP "BIT_1".
BIT_1:  MOV [ BYTE PTR SI ], '1'        
NEXT_BIT:                    
        DEC SI                   ;NEXT BIT POSITION IS TO THE LEFT.
        DEC CL
        JNZ BINL1
        POP CX
        JMP PRINTBINARY
```

**3.** Finally, display "str1" (ended by '$'):

```
PRINTBINARY:    CURSOR 36,22 ; 36,22 then 35,22 to 33,22
                MOV AH, 9              ;SERVICE TO DISPLAY STRING '$' ENDED.
                MOV DX, OFFSET STR1    ;STRING TO DISPLAY ('$' ENDED).
                INT 21H
                JMP L0
```

Comment: Ah i see, thanks a lot for editing my code and pointing about my mistakes, i see now that shifting would be better than dividing. Also realized that since ill be displaying a string in printbinary, i dont need to have a loop to move to change the cursor backwards each time. Thanks again, will test code and reply :) The code works flawlessly, thank you. Id like to state that the reason im moving the resulting binary code to a string is so that i can use it later to send that binary to the LED segment so that i can display the respective number, thanks again Jose :)

Comment: Just have a question for you jose. If i want to move the string to a memory or register so i can use the OUT function to send it to any port, would this work? (added to end of question)

Comment: You will need a loop to send char by char to the port.

Comment: I see, would it work if i copy each char by char to another string, lets say str2, move the value in str2 to for example CX, and then use the out function like this:  OUT DX,CX (CX containing str2, and DX containing respective port) ?

Comment: Nope. You need a normal loop and send each individual char to the port.